# Cannot convert type 'string' to 'string[]' In my Class

Tags: c#

I have some problem when i try Get Rank of worker.

I have Class Worker, and i want to display worker rank in console, but i have this trouble.

```
namespace GYA.HW4.OOP.Classes.Classes {
    class Worker {
        public string[] Ranks { get; set; }

        public int CapacityOfDetails { get; set; }
        public Worker() {
            this.Ranks = new string[3] { "Не опытный", "Опытный", "Мастер" };
        }
        public string[] GetRanks() {
            return this.Ranks;
        }
    }
}
```

And my Class where i want to display it:

```
namespace GYA.HW4.OOP.Classes.Classes {
    class ProcessBuilding {
        public bool BuildUnit(Worker[] workers, Unit unit) {
            for (int i = 0; i < workers.Length; i++) {
                unit.Details += workers[i].CapacityOfDetails;//type
            }
            if (unit.Details == unit.CountOfDetailsForDone) {
                unit.StatusDone = true;
            } else {
                unit.StatusDone = false;
            }
            return unit.StatusDone;
        }
        public Worker[] AssignWorkers(int countOfWorkers) {
            Random randomizer = new Random();
            Worker[] workers = new Worker[countOfWorkers];
            for (int i = 0; i < workers.Length; i++) {   
                int randomNumber = randomizer.Next(0, 2);
                workers[i] = new Worker();
                workers[i].Ranks = workers[i].GetRanks()[randomNumber]; <= (Troubles is here)
                if (randomNumber == 0 ) {
                    workers[i].CapacityOfDetails = 1;
                }else if(randomNumber == 1) {
                    workers[i].CapacityOfDetails = 3;
                } else if (randomNumber == 2) {
                    workers[i].CapacityOfDetails = 5;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Рабочий с рангом {workers[i].Ranks} установил {workers[i].CapacityOfDetails} детал(ь/и)");
            }
            return workers;
        }     
    }
}
```

How can i do this?
sorry for stupid question, i just learning

Comment: can you add better description of the problem?  is this a compile problem?  if so which line?  if this is runtime problem, what is the exception and where is it thrown?

Comment: @i.do.stuff As I understand it, it's a compilation problem, the compilation error is given as the title of this question. The line of the error is written in the snippet provided. "<= (Troubles is here)" . But OP should confirm that, if possible.

Comment: You're trying to assign string to array of strings, you can't do this. Either redesign your Worker class or assign it like so `workers[i].Ranks = new [] {workers[i].GetRanks()[randomNumber]};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a class design issue. Your Worker class has a Ranks field, which is apparently used for two different things. First, you store ALL the possible ranks there. Then later you try to use it for a rank of a particular instance of Worker.

As a side linguistical note, "Не опытный" does not fit the context, should be "Неопытный" as this is a lasting property of the subject.

To solve your issue, you need to separate the concepts. Something like:

```
namespace GYA.HW4.OOP.Classes.Classes 
{
    public class Worker 
    {
        public static readonly string[] AllRanks => new [] { "Неопытный", "Опытный", "Мастер" };

        public string Rank { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
workers[i].Rank = Worker.AllRanks[randomNumber]; // (No troubles here anymore)
```

and then

```
Console.WriteLine($"A {workers[i].Rank} worker installed {workers[i].CapacityOfDetails} tool(s)");
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i need!

Comment: this is the core issue addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing the internal details of an implementation like the kind of collections you are using can be a problem – your users will depend on you using an array. And they can manipulate the content of the collections directly.

You really should separate the implementation from interface:

```
class Worker {
  private List<string> theRanks = new List<string>();

  public ICollection<string> Ranks {
    get {
      return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(theRanks);
    }
  }

  public void AddRank(string newRank) {
    theRanks.Add(newRank);
  }
}
```

And I solve you add problem by using a collection to which I can easily add. `Array` is fixed length and adding to it means copying (and breaking any references clients could have taken when exposed directly).

So your

> ```
> workers[i].Ranks = workers[i].GetRanks()[randomNumber];
> ```

becomes

```
works[i].AddRank(workers[i].Ranks[randomNumber]);
```

Comment: I'm still not learned the lists, this why i try do this just with arrays

Comment: @Taifunov I would suggest start to use `List<T>`: it is almost always the better option.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
workers[i].Ranks = workers[i].GetRanks()[randomNumber];
```

...the part `workers[i].Ranks` is a string array.

When you are calling `workers[i].GetRanks()[randomNumber]`, you get a single string.
You can not put a single string where an array is expected.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation of the error :

```
workers[i].Ranks = workers[i].GetRanks()[randomNumber]
```

`Ranks` is defined as an array of string.

`GetRanks()` returns an array of string.

`GetRanks()[randomNumber]` will return a single string. That cannot be assigned to `Ranks`.

### "Quick and dirty" solution

Maybe you want to create a new array containing only one string ?

In this case you can create a new array :

```
workers[i].Ranks = new string[] { workers[i].GetRanks()[randomNumber] };
```

### However

As other have pointed out, on the overall this is not a recommended way of manipulating arrays, you probably expose and manipulate too many details (the string arrray) outside your class). And worse of all, the main confusion is caused by you trying to use `Ranks` for two different purposes (store alll the possible values and store the actual chosen random value)

As strictly reading your program, if you just need to print the value on the console, I would at least avoid manipulating the Ranks things from outside the class. This currently violate the OOP [encapsulation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) and [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

It seems to me you want to assign a random rank to your worker when creating them.
Then the predefined list of possible rank should not be an instance variable, but more a static variable.

You could use a method on the Worker object to take care of selecting the possible rank and assign the correct value for the other field :

### Reviewed code with improved separation of concerns and encapsulation :

```
class Worker {
    private static string[] AvailableRanks = new string[3] { "Не опытный", "Опытный", "Мастер" };

    public string Rank { get; private set; }
    public int CapacityOfDetails { get; private set; }

    public Worker() {
    }

    public AssignRandomRank(Random randomizer) {
        int randomNumber = randomizer.Next(0, 2);
        this.Rank = AvailableRanks[randomNumber];
        if (randomNumber == 0 ) {
            CapacityOfDetails = 1;
        } else if(randomNumber == 1) {
            CapacityOfDetails = 3;
        } else if (randomNumber == 2) {
            CapacityOfDetails = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the other class :

```
    // the only concern of this method is creating the workers, initialize them and do a console log of the work.
    // The worker class itself *knows* how to initialize itself.
    // much more clearer, in my opinion 

    public Worker[] AssignWorkers(int countOfWorkers) {
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[countOfWorkers];
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.Length; i++) {  
            workers[i] = new Worker();
            workers[i].AssignRandomRank(randomizer);

            Console.WriteLine($"Рабочий с рангом {workers[i].Ranks} установил {workers[i].CapacityOfDetails} детал(ь/и)");
        }
        return workers;
    }
```

Note that there is still room for better refactoring / improvement.

But that would be maybe more fitted for [codereview.se].